# read_csv in pandas - how to use a specific row as header

Tags: python, pandas

tring to parse this file :

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7714935

that looks like :

```
metadata line
metadata line
metadata line
metadata line
metadata line
metadata line
metadata line 
metadata line
metadata line
metadata line
metadata line
metadata line
metadata line
metadata line
metadata line
metadata line
metadata line
metadata line
metadata line
metadata line
metadata line
metadata line

col1   col2         col3    UTCDate   UTCTime       col6       col7   
                           (m)      (MDY)     (sec)    (weeks)      (MDY)     
string1- string2-        0.000 11/06/2013 313585.10 1765.00000 11/06/2013 
string1- string2-        0.000 11/06/2013 313585.30 1765.00000 11/06/2013 
...
```

i can read it using a code like :

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
names=['col1','col2','col3','UTCDate','UTCTime','col6','col7']

def parse(UTCDate,UTCTime):
    return dt.datetime.strptime(UTCDate, '%m/%d/%Y') + dt.timedelta(seconds=float(UTCTime))

df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=r'\s+', skiprows=25, index_col='date', parse_dates={'date':['UTCDate','UTCTime']}, names=names, date_parser=parse)
```

Is there a way to avoid to specify the "names" in a list, and try to parse the
header instead ?

header is the line :

```
col1   col2         col3    UTCDate   UTCTime       col6       col7
```

line 24 in the gist. 
I was thinking to keep_date_col=True, header=0 and pass a list of lines to skip like [arange(0,23),25] .. but didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think your general approach is ok. Where I think it fails, for me at least, is with the delimiter and the `Longitude` / `Latitude` columns. Your delimiter is '\s+' however the data in these columns then looks like three columns rather than one.

```
Latitude        Longitude
41 20 54.57907  -70 38 14.25924
```

Maybe you could replace all double whitespaces with a tab and use the tab as a delimiter. Alternatively, if you only need the first seven columns, simply remove the remainder before giving it to the dataframe.

Comment: I need all the columns, i reduced the example to 7 col, to reduce the complexity of the question. the problem with : latitude and longitude is solved because in the names i declared additional columns  ('LatD','LatM','LatS','LonD','LonM','LonS')

Comment: I should use a converter on the 2 field to store the longitude and latitude values using a different notation (decimal degree perhaps) so to preserve the same columns names in the df as in the header.

Comment: I reckon both approaches should be ok. Did you get it to work?

Comment: Not yet, trying your approach i've trouble to understand how replace the separator, without looping trough the file line by line  (my real data can hundred thousands lines). Once i got this resolved i can try to use  "linecache.getline" in order to generate the list of "names" :  header = linecache.getline(r, 24)
" ".join(header.split()).split(' ')

Comment: nothing, the replacing double space with tabs will work but not for all the columns, some of them are single spaced

Comment: Hm, I can't see other problems in your data besides the lat/long at the moment. You could read the header line and replace lat/long with your approach above, `'LatD','LatM','LatS','LonD','LonM','LonS'`, read the file from just below the header, using whitespace as a delimiter and apply the previously read and amended header line as an index to the new dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it overly elegant, but you could generalize this problem to dealing with a variable number of rows to skip, with some help from csv

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

counter=0
testfile=open(filename, 'r')
filereader = csv.reader(testfile, delimiter=r'\s+')
for row in filereader :
    counter += 1 #Keep track of row number
    if 'col1' in row: #Or whatever string you're looking for as the first row
        finalcount=counter

Output=pd.read_csv(filename,sep=r'\s+',skiprows=finalcount-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `header=#` arg for `read_csv()`?

Like `pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=r'\s+', skiprows=25, index_col='date', parse_dates={'date':['UTCDate','UTCTime']}, header=26, date_parser=parse)`

Docs state:

> > header : int, list of ints
> >         Row number(s) to use as the column names, and the start of the
> >         data.  Defaults to 0 if no `names` passed, otherwise `None`. Explicitly
> >         pass `header=0` to be able to replace existing names. The header can be
> >         a list of integers that specify row locations for a multi-index on the
> >         columns E.g. [0,1,3]. Intervening rows that are not specified will be
> >         skipped (e.g. 2 in this example are skipped). Note that this parameter
> >         ignores commented lines and empty lines if `skip_blank_lines=True`, so header=0
> >         denotes the first line of data rather than the first line of the file.